# How to use Bluemix Build and Deploy Test Job with PHP Unit Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, deployment, phpunit, ibm-cloud

I am trying to setup a build and deploy pipeline on Bluemix for my PHP application. I am using PHPUnit for testing but can't seem to get the test stage to call PHPUnit because it isn't installed. The Build and Deploy stages work perfectly for me I am just trying to add a test stage between them. The problem is that PHP isn't even installed in the test stage. I quick php -v will give a command not found error. Do I have to install php, apache, composer, and phpunit just to get this test stage to work? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up installing apache, php7, and composer in order to get phpunit working. Here are the commands I ran during a test stage. There are some echo and ls statements that I was using to help me debug the installations. My tests are under the tests folder in the root of my directory like test/exampleTest.php and I have phpunit create an xml output file called tests/Test.xml and then supply that file to the box asking "Test Result File Pattern" so then Bluemix can read that file to know if the Tests succeeded or failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# invoke tests here
echo "  adding repo"
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
echo "  updating apt-get"
sudo apt-get -y update
echo " installing apache2"
sudo apt-get -y install apache2
echo " installing php7.0"
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-xml php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-bz2
echo " PHP TESTING"
php -v
echo " PHP TESTING 2"
php -r 'echo "\n\nYour PHP installation is working fine.\n\n\n";'
echo "  downloading composer"
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
echo "  installing composer"
php composer.phar install
echo "  ls"
ls
echo "  ls ../"
ls ../
echo "  ls vendor"
ls vendor
echo "  running tests"
vendor/bin/phpunit --log-junit tests/Test.xml --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my previous discussions with the Bluemix DevOps team, you will have to install each of those dependencies to get the testing stage to work.

Comment: I shared your feedback with the development team. Let me know if your question is resolved.

Comment: Is there a way to run tests on a deployed environment? So that I could deploy my app to say test.example.com run some tests on it without having to install php, apache, ... because it would be installed by the deploy build pack, and then if it works deploy to production site production.example.com?

Comment: You could probably configure a staging app for testing and a production app . So, one project could be used for testing and if it works, have another project set up for production. If you have any specific feedback or questions for the IBM Bluemix DevOps Services team, you can contact them at hub@jazz.net.